# Return String in DataHandler

Tags: java, string, web-services, datahandler

I've created a web service in `Java` that returns a `DataHandler`.
This has to be able to return a `File`, which works fine.
But it should also be able to return a `String`.
Any idea how I can transfer a `String` with a `DataHandler`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[JavaMail](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavax.mail%7Cjavax.mail-api%7C1.4.6%7Cjar) has a `ByteArrayDataSource` that you can use for this purpose:

```
DataSource ds = new ByteArrayDataSource(theString, "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(ds);
```

The `charset` in the mime type determines what encoding it will use to convert the string to bytes.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out when I tried it in a new project for testing. But when I implement it in my current project and try to run it I'm getting a 'WebServiceException: failed to access the WSDL'. I don't have this error if I send a file with a FileDataSource...

Comment: After further testing and logging: the ByteArrayDataSource constructor causes my webMethod to be called again (once) and does nothing...
It doesn't even throw an exception of any kind