# Already Encoded String as DataHandler

Tags: java, web-services, encoding, datahandler

So after looking at [a similar SO Post about String and DataHandlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221418/return-string-in-datahandler), I have run into a problem in terms of efficiency.  I have a String coming into my web service that is already encoded.  I have the need to convert this String into a `DataHandler` to put into a POJO and send off to another service.  When I use `new ByteArrayDataSource(String, type)` it is encoding the already encoded String (a 2nd time).

To work around this I am decoding the input, and then passing the created `byte[]` into `new ByteArrayDataSource(byte[], type)`.  I am worried about the performance hit this will create when having to decode and re-encode images, when I already have an encoded version being passed in.  Is there a way to create a `DataHandler` (or `DataSource`) from an already encoded String without needing the "MIME type", so I don't have to decode to encode?

I have tried using `FileDataSource(String)` but this was not working, with the same input used in a working `ByteArrayDataSource(byte[], String)` with decoded Strings.  I also tried it passing in a blank string for the type using `ByteArrayDataSource(String, type)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit more searching I came across an Apache library that does this, but I am not sure how much more efficient it would be.  [Apache Axis2 has a ConverterUtil class](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/databinding/utils/ConverterUtil.html#convertToDataHandler%28java.lang.String%29) that looks to have a lot of binary manipulation methods for Strings.

Looking into that code a bit more, the code for `convertToDataHandler(String)` just passes the String along to the `convertToBase64Binary(String)` function.  This is just creating a new ByteArrayDataSource from the String by decoding it and then going forward.  So the util is just wrapping up the functionality I am already doing.